# socket send call getting blocked for so long

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, tcp

I send 2 bytes of app data on the socket(blocking) every 10 seconds, but the send call got blocked in the last instance in below long for more than 40 seconds.

- 2012-06-13 12:02:46.653417|INFO|before send
- 2012-06-13 12:02:46.653457|INFO|after send (2)
- 2012-06-13 12:02:57.566898|INFO|before send
- 2012-06-13 12:02:57.566962|INFO|after send (2)
- 2012-06-13 12:03:08.234060|INFO|before send
- 2012-06-13 12:03:08.234101|INFO|after send (2)
- **2012-06-13 12:03:19.010743|INFO|before send
- 2012-06-13 12:04:00.969162|INFO|after send (2)**

The tcp default send buffer size on machine(linux) is 65536.

The 2 bytes data is to heartbeat with a server and server expects client to send HB once atleast every 15 seconds.

Also, I did not disable naggle's algorithm.

The question is - can the send call blocked so long like 40 secs? And it is happening only sporadically, it happened after close to 12 hours of running.

The send call I know should just copy the data to TCP send buffer.

publish is called every 10 seconds. No its not gradual slow down of send call. It happens once suddenly and then due to that socket on other side gets closed, so the app exits.

```
int publish(char* buff, int size) const {
      /* Adds the 0x0A to the end */
      buff[size]=_eolchar;

      if (_debugMode)
      {
          ACE_DEBUG((MY_INFO "before send\n"));
      }

      int ret = _socket.send((void*)buff, size+1);

      if (_debugMode)
      {
          ACE_DEBUG((MY_INFO "after send (%d)\n", ret));
          //std::cout << "after send " << ret << std::endl;
      }

      if (ret < 1)
      {
          ACE_DEBUG((MY_ERROR "Socket error, FH going down\n"));
          ACE_OS::sleep(1);
          abort();
      }
      return ret;
 }
```

Comment: What exactly is the question?  Sometimes packets can get delayed...

Comment: Please give the code which is doing the send call

Comment: How often is publish() being called?  Have you tested your ACE_DEBUG call to see how long that takes?  Do you notice a slowdown over time or just the one 40 second block then it goes back to normal?

Comment: publish is called every 10 seconds. No its not gradual slow down of send call. It happens once suddenly and then due to that socket on other side gets closed, so the app exits. ACE_DEBUG is only added for sake of printing trace, issue happens without ACE_DEBUG also.

Comment: From that all I can say is probably the send is blocking for a while, which happens sometimes depending on packet loss etc.

Comment: @Medicine Hey! You are an ACE user too !! :-) Nice to see that.. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using the blocking `send()` call, in the viewpoint of your application, you can think of the remote TCP buffer, the network and the local sending TCP buffer, as one big buffer.

That is, if the remote application gets delayed in reading new bytes from its TCP buffer, eventually your local TCP buffer will become (nearly) full. If you try to `send()` a new payload that overflows the TCP buffer, the `send()` implementation (the kernel system call) won't return the focus to your application until the TCP buffer gets enough room to store that payload.

The only way to reach that state is when the remote application does not read enough bytes. A typical scenario in *test* environment is when the remote application pauses on a breakpoint ... :-)

This is what we call a **SLOW CONSUMER** issue. If you share that diagnosis, then there are multiple ways of getting rid of that issue:

1. If you have control over the remote application, make it *fast* enough so that the local application won't get blocked.
2. If you don't have the control of the remote application, then there could be multiple answers:

   - It can be ok for your own needs to block up to 40 seconds.
   - If not so, you need to use an unblocking version of the `send()` system call. From here, there are multiple possible policies; I describe one below. (Hold on please! :-) )

You can try to use a dynamic array which acts as a fake sending TCP FIFO and grows when the sending call returns you `EWOULDBLOCK`. In this case you likely have to use the `select()` system call to detect when the remote application keeps up with the pace and send it the unseen data first.

It can be a little bit trickier that the simple `publish()` function you have here (while quite common in most of network applications). You have to know also there is no guarantee that the dynamic buffer grows to the point you no longer have any free memory, and then your local application could crash. A typical policy in "real-time" network application is to choose an arbitrary maximum size for the buffer which close the TCP connection when reached, thus avoiding your local application to get run out of free memory. Choose that max wisely, since it depends on the number of potential slow consumer connections.

Comment: As a side note, another typical SLOW CONSUMER scenario is when two application communicates through a very slow/long WAN. I encounter that case one time through a WAN from Japan to Australia. The remote application was ok, but the WAN was so slow..

Comment: could this be because the naggle's algorithm is not turned off? I am only sending 2 bytes of data(plus tcp header). (But for 12 hours every 10 seconds, the data was sent in micro seconds time to the remote host, so I doubt the naggle's algorithm is issue here). remote host's receive window size is 8192 bytes.

Comment: @Medicine Are you able to check out the log files on the remote application side?

Comment: @Medicine oh. Are you working in Market access developemnt team ? I do.

Comment: Currently in CACIB and I've been also in SGCIB for three years.:-)

Comment: cool..I just moved from OMS to Market Data team, hence the system programming issues ;)

Comment: And by the way I don't think that Nagle can be an issue here. I would actually advise to turn it on. Because in the case your WAN has a low throughput, Nagle takes care to optimize it and avoid losing bandwith with flooding the line with too much TCP packets. Now about your line, do you have information? Did you launch ping and get a look at the latencies? There may be some tools like TCPDUMP on Linux or Wireshark on WindowsOS which could help a lot to detect network issues. While a little complicated to analyze when not used to do so, to my own taste.. :-)

Comment: the same app has no issues when run on 2 other boxes :( so its getting complicated to diagnoise, may be the OS settings/NIC have a problem. tcpdump said clearly that we didn't send heartbeat until timeout. the data which the exchange sent was quickly acked and the earlier heartbeats were quickly acked by the exchange. Also there are total of 6 feed handlers running on the box. 2 of them belong to the same exchange, both of them are going down same time and one of the other exchange's feed handler is going down as well.

Comment: @Medicine Yes if two other boxes has no problems, I guess there are some chances that, actually, the issue come from the initial device...

Comment: this is Linux OS...not sure what system parameters needs to be checked. Also there is another problem with another feed handler with a different exchange where the exchange says that we are a slow consumer and disconnects. we took a tcpdump until the disconnect and see that we have not decreased our receive window. Its fairly constant at 24576 until the disconnect. If the exchange queues up more than 2500 updates (total for all instruments subscribed) then it disconnects with us with reason as slow consumer. but tcp recv window on our side didnt decrease, any idea?

Comment: not sure how non-blocking sockets help here, because if I cannot actually send the data to the remote host in 5 seconds, the connection will be disconnected. Its not that I want to get the cpu cycles which are lost in a blocking socket. with all the evidence above, I have a feeling something is wrong with the box itself.

Answer (score 1):

The following(and more that I am not gonna mention now) are considered blocking system calls:
send, connect, recv, accept.

What this means is that they can block as far as they need till the specified job is done.
So yes, send can block for 40 seconds and more, depending on how much time it takes to send the data; though I cannot know why it blocked that long in your specific case.

If you want to avoid this blocking, I advice you to read about asynchronous sockets and I/O.
They MIGHT prove to solve part of your problem.

Comment: Thanks. send taking that long should imply that the underlying network link is bad, correct? heavy packet loss, may be?

Comment: @Medicine when there is too much packet loss, I would say (while not sure) that at some point a TCP RESET would happen. And then you should see the send() returning you an error.

Comment: @Adel, not sure how non-blocking sockets help here, because if I cannot actually send the data to the remote host in 5 seconds, the connection will be disconnected. Its not that I want to get the cpu cycles which are lost in a blocking socket.