# Why socket BeginSend would take too long

Tags: c#, sockets

I have the following code

```
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(data);
        IAsyncResult res = socket.BeginSend(bytes, 0, bytes.Length, 0, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), socket);
        int waitingCounter = 0;
        while (!res.IsCompleted && waitingCounter<10)
        {
            if (Tracing.TraceInfo) Tracing.WriteLine("Waiting for data to be transmited. Give a timeout of 1 second", _traceName);
            Thread.Sleep(1 * 1000);
            waitingCounter++;
        }
```

This code has been installed in many machines, but there are some cases where the condition res.IsCompleted takes long to become true.

The reason is related with the network maybe a firewall, proxy? or to the client (too slow) or to the server?

I have not been able to reproduce this scenario.

**Edit:** I try to reproduce the error by using an [asynchronous client and a synchronous server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bew39x2a.aspx)

with the following modifications:
Client=>

```
while (true) { 
        Send(client, "This is a test<EOF>");
        sendDone.WaitOne();
}
```

Server=>

```
while (true){
         Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");
         // Program is suspended while waiting for an incoming connection.
         Socket handler = listener.Accept();
         data = null;

         // Show the data on the console.
         Console.WriteLine("Text received : {0}", data);

         handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
         handler.Close();
}
```

In the second Send(), I get a socket exception. What is normal because the server is not reading the data.
But actually what I want to reproduce is:

Waiting for data to be transmited. Give a timeout of 1 second
Waiting for data to be transmited. Give a timeout of 1 second
Waiting for data to be transmited. Give a timeout of 1 second
Waiting for data to be transmited. Give a timeout of 1 second
Waiting for data to be transmited. Give a timeout of 1 second

As it happens in one of our installations

Edit:
An answer disappeared from this question!!!

Comment: Define `takes long`, 1 second? 5 seconds?

Comment: It depends on the client and on the time. Sometimes I see 3 sometimes 10 seconds

Comment: Normally the IsCompleted of BeginSend doesn't mean the bytes are actually sent, but that it is queued in the sendbuffer.

Comment: Exactly!, then why it takes so long to put the bytes in the queue?

Comment: Could it be something to do with the ThreadPool being too busy?

Comment: Yes, it could. But then how do I check it?

Comment: You could try this in you while loop `getavailablethreads`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.getavailablethreads.aspx

Comment: Remember that the problem is at the client, and I can not reproduce it. There is somewhere in windows where I can configure the maxNumber of threads?

Comment: `ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads()` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.setmaxthreads.aspx **BUT** normally you should not change it, there is probably something else stalling your network or ThreadPool. You should try to find it. Do you use any type of locking within the EndSend? I think the IsCompleted will be set when the AsyncCallback is completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though `BeginSend` won't stall your application, it should still have the same constraints as `Send`. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11038452/1244630) answer explains why things could go wrong (I've paraphrased):

> For your application, the TCP buffer, the network and the local
>   sending TCP buffer is one big buffer. **If the remote application gets
>   delayed in reading new bytes** from its TCP buffer, eventually your
>   local TCP buffer will end up being (nearly) full. The send won't
>   complete until the TCP buffer has enough space to store the payload
>   you're trying to send.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have found the solution in 2014. Actually the problem was that the receiving machine was blocked and was not reading the data. So we had to redesign the protocol. Sorry I have not documented the solution here in Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget when the first check `res.IsCompleted`, you are always waiting a second for the next check.

Comment: Yes, actually the normal log file wil print "Waiting for data to be transmited. Give a timeout of 1 second" at least once